# Need to Upload A file of maximum 15 GB size into SharePoint Document Library. Any app

Tags: sharepoint

I need to upload a document of size maximum upto 15gb in Sharepoint document library. Tried multiple approaches such as creating ASP.net web Application and hosting in IIS and saving the file as chunks but since IIS restricts file size to 2 gb , it is not working.

Kindly help me with any references or code snippets usng JSOM/CSOM/Server side coding will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SharePoint onpremise.

- SharePoint 2013 filesize limits is 2GB - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#list-and-library-limits)
- SharePoint 2016 default filesize is 2GB and can be increased to 10GB - [docs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34128.sharepoint-2016-file-size-limit.aspx)
- SharePoint 2019 filesize limits is 15GB (same as SPO) - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-2019#increased-storage-file-size-in-sharepoint-document-libraries)

So you may be limited by SharePoint itself rather than IIS.

However if your SharePoint configuration and version does allow files more than 2GB then you may need to configure the IIS upload limit. Details of how to do this can be found in [this blog](https://hoststud.com/resources/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-file-size-in-iis.422/)